# Award someone else's answer with your bounty by mis-click

Tags: feature-request, support, bounties

Unfortunately I have awarded a bounty to the wrong answer while I wanted to award it to another answer. Can I take back my points to award someone else's answer?

Comment: By the way, if you mark an answer as accepted while the bounty is still active, I think it automatically give the bounty to that answer.

Comment: @ Sha Wiz Dow Ard Unfortunatley is not giving the points to the marked answear :|

Comment: Because you did that after granting the bounty..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

You can start a new bounty and award it to the correct answer.

It may be possible for a dev to do this for you - if so, I am sure they can post here and confirm if possible.

Comment: cool, but this is a wrong behaivior because if a dumb by mistake press that bounty award button ... a nice feature is to have a behaviour like accepted answear option... and if someone give you a better answear to award that answear!

Comment: Btw, it's "answer", not "answear".

Comment: No, it is not wrong. The assumption is that people are careful when awarding bounties.

Comment: @RulerNature This is by design so people aren't juggling about large amounts of reputation. You should try to make sure if is the correct answer *before* you award. They're one-time things to award, not a method to juggle to the best answer at any time. it's meant to get answers fast.

Comment: @Oded yes but when the things are dynamically designed I think is a better way

Comment: @RulerNature - I have no idea what that means.

Comment: @RulerNature Nor do I. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Oded,@ObsessiveSSO it means to have a button like take your points back till bounty will expire or to award another answer.

Comment: @RulerNature you get big and very clear message asking you to confirm before giving the bounty. We can't really ask for more. It's not one misclick, it's at least two, plus **misread** of messages. Sometimes one have to pay for his mistakes, it's really not the end of the world.

Comment: @Sha Wiz Dow Ard yes I know but I'm upset because I don't awarded correct answer.

Comment: For the record, moderators can cancel active bounty (thus refunding the points) but can't "roll back" bounty that was already given. Devs can do anything with direct access to the database, but can't see any reason for any divine intervention like this on such a case.

Comment: @RulerNature fair enough and you have full right to be upset, but I disagree that we should have ability to do what you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

No, once the bounty is set, there is no way to retrieve the points back, cancel or change the bounty. It says so when you are trying to start a bounty too.

In your case you could try to contact the support, or just live with it.

Comment: cool, but this is a wrong behaivior because if a dumb by mistake press that bounty award button ... a nice feature is to have a behaviour like accepted answear option... and if someone give you a better answear to award that answear!

Comment: Nope, just be careful awarding. It's not all that hard.